# Trying to get user profile info from Azure using Graph

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to get user profile info from Azure using Graph. If I download one of the samples, it works, but I can't figure it out for a real app. I haven't had any issues registering the app in the new app portal, but I am unable to successfully view the user profile data. Here's some code:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> About() {
    try {
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal
            .Current
            .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
            .Value;

        TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, this.HttpContext)
            .GetMsalCacheInstance();

        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
            clientId,
            redirectUri,
            new ClientCredential(appKey),
            userTokenCache,
            null);

        if (cca.Users.Count() > 0) {

            string[] scopes = { "User.Read" };

            AuthenticationResult result =
                await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, cca.Users.First());

            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.AccessToken);

            HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/");
            string rez = await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            ViewBag.Message = rez;

            ViewBag.UserName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;

        } else { }
        return View();
    } catch (MsalUiRequiredException) {
        ViewBag.Relogin = "true";
        return View();
    } catch (Exception eee) {
        ViewBag.Error = "An error has occurred. Details: " + eee.Message;
        return View();
    }
}
```

After logging in, I get nothing in the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
@{
    if (ViewBag.Error != null)
    {
        <p class="red">Error: @ViewBag.Error</p>
    }
}

<div>Name: @ViewBag.UserName</div>
<div>ObjectId: @ViewBag.ObjectId </div>
<div>Given Name: @ViewBag.GivenName </div>
<div>Surname: @ViewBag.Surname </div>
<div>UPN: @ViewBag.UPN</div>
<div>Home phone: @ViewBag.HomePhone</div>
<div>Mobile phone: @ViewBag.MobileNumber</div>
<div>Other phone: @ViewBag.OtherPhone</div>
<div>User Data: @ViewBag.UserData</div>
```

Comment: What are you getting for an error?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I get no error.  It just doesn't seem to work.  None of the fields I have listed are populated despite the fact that I am logged in.

Comment: You're getting an error but you're capturing the exceptions so you'll need to look at your debugger to figure out what is happening.